# Retrieve device id sent to to Exchange ActiveSync server

Tags: android, exchange-server

Assuming several devices can be associated with the same Exchange ActiveSync account, I'm looking for a way to correlate between the specific device my app is running on and the device as it's defined in exchange server.

Is there any API way to retrieve the device id sent to exchange server?

this seems to be different between OEMs, so looking at the android exchange support source code wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple exchange clients that run on android devices (Google's client on the nexus 1/s, HTC's client on their devices, touchdown which is an exchange client app, Etc).

Every android exchange client chooses its own ID-generation method. thus there seems to be no API for retrieving such an ID.